# How do I print blank for 7th lowest place on a list or higher?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXS9o.png)

For the 'Place' column A, I want it to leave the cell blank for 7th place and above. Referencing the 'Final Time' column. The rest of my formula works fine, I just don't want it so say 'FALSE' and am trying to avoid putting in a specific formula for every placing.

Comment: Please do not post a picture of your code. Those that may be in the position to help you will not want to re-type all of that formula again themselves when trying to figure out what is wrong with it. Also make sure in your Question, you are actually asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

After the very last `"6"` you are missing a `, ""` Excel will default to the value FALSE if you do not specify a value to insert for false.

However I strongly recommend reading up on the RANK function.

Comment: That works to not place above 7th however, now if I don't have 6 values it just returns #NUM...which is a possibility. Could you clarify what may fix this?

Comment: I noticed you started removing the [tag:jlink] tag from all Mathematica questions. You should be aware that J/Link is the name of the Java interface of Mathematica, and the tag was used for this for several years (before the Mathematica community moved to their own SE site).  It does not seem like a good idea to one-sidedly remove all these uses of the tag before a prior discussion.

Comment: Sorry I was just basing it off of the tags description, and I'm not sure this comment section is the place to discuss it.

Comment: @kcahill I don't know what you are asking, and your question **still** has an image rather then the formula in text.